# PHP slugify method without using preg_replace()

Tags: php, pcre

I am using following slugify method,in my local dev its working fine,but in my production server(CentOs) and the PCRE UTF8 supported but "No Unicode properties support".

```
function slugify($text)
{
    // replace non letter or digits by -
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);

    // trim
    $text = trim($text, '-');

    // transliterate
    if (function_exists('iconv')) {
        $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    }

    // lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);

    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

    if (empty($text)) {
        return 'n-a';
    }
    return $text;
}
```

And preg_replace is not working there,is there any method that can work as preg_replace,or any slugify muthod that can work as the above function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need UTF8 support if you have already made a translitertion to us-ascii?

Define "not working"

Comment: Why has this been voted down...?

Comment: I need unicode properties support actually

Comment: slugify function returning 'n-a'

Comment: If you need unicode properties support, you need to enable it. If you are on a shared host, your hosting provider should do that for you. I can't think of anything else other than having some tables to replace characters for the specific language to their respective non-unicode letters. Like `$trans = array('ä' => 'a', 'å' => 'a', 'ö' => 'o'); $slug = strtr($string, $trans);`. After the translations have been done, discard anything other than `A-Za-z0-9`.

Comment: Actually *what* is not working with your code? *How* does the "not working" look like? What do you want your slugify method to do? Just remove all characters that are not part of the `us-ascii` charset? And you have two regexes, which one fails? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Both are failing,I have written this small function to solve it without regex  ""static  public function slugify($text)
    {

        $temp = explode(" ",$text);
        $slug = trim(strtolower(implode("-", $temp)));
        return $slug;

    }""

Comment: This is not a valid solution I know,doing it as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the same issue described here: http://chrisjean.com/2009/01/31/unicode-support-on-centos-52-with-php-and-pcre/. I've run into it before myself, and that link is how I fixed it (or rather, how our sysadmin fixed it).

Essentially, the \pL in the first regex will not run or compile if you do not have "Unicode properties support".